# Is there a way to disable a radio button in leaflets layer control?

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I am looking for a way to select/disable a single radio button in my base map. Here is my code.

This creates the baseMap for myleaflet layer

```
baseMap = {
    Map View: mapQuestOpenEnglish
    Satelite View: mapQuestAerial
}

mapControl = L.control.layers(baseMap)
```

Eventually I add mapControl to the map and it produces the following html

```
<div class="leaflet-control-layers leaflet-control" aria-haspopup="true">
  <a class="leaflet-control-layers-toggle" href="#" title="Layers"></a>
  <form class="leaflet-control-layers-list">
    <div class="leaflet-control-layers-base">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers" checked="checked">
        <span> 
          <span class="default-map">Map View</span>
        </span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers">
        <span> 
          <span class="staelite-map">Satelite View</span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I want a way to be able to select/disable this radio button.

```
<input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers">
```

Is there any easy way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can't you do it with pure javascript?

Comment: I'm sure its possible but I'm not sure how to select the radio button through all the html without any handle to it. Also it doesn't seem like a clean way to do it.

Comment: Yes, true... may not be very clean, but it's possible. Are you targeting this specific scenario? with only two radios?

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to be pretty open ended. To be able target any radio button regardless of the position of the button.

Comment: It seems to me that the only element that differs from one another is the span label, like `staelite-map`, `default-map`... If you could target the radio by those classes, would that be enough?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not very clean, but works...

You can select the desired radio element through it's respective span label's class. Here's a simple JS method to do that:

```
function SelectRadio(span_class) {
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName(span_class)[0];
    var radio = span.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('radio')[0];
    return radio;
}
```

You just call it like this:

```
var element = SelectRadio('staelite-map');
/* Here you'll have the DOM Element. Just use it to enable/disable,
      set selection, or anything else */
```

Comment: I actually didn't notice there was a class already attached to the span. So I guess I might just go with your way. I'm going to let the question sit for a bit to see if there is a way to do it inside of leaflet but if not I'll make your answer the selected answer. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: No problem... I hope you can figure it out!